# Data race when GOMAXPROCS=1

Tags: go, race-condition

I'm trying to understand one of the Golang [typical data races](http://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html#Unprotected_global_variable) where access to an unprotected global variable from multiple goroutines may cause a race condition:

```
var service map[string]net.Addr

func RegisterService(name string, addr net.Addr) {
  service[name] = addr
}

func LookupService(name string) net.Addr {
  return service[name]
}
```

It goes on to say that we can solve this by protecting it with a mutex:

```
var (
  service   map[string]net.Addr
  serviceMu sync.Mutex
)

func RegisterService(name string, addr net.Addr) {
  serviceMu.Lock()
  defer serviceMu.Unlock()
  service[name] = addr
}

func LookupService(name string) net.Addr {
  serviceMu.Lock()
  defer serviceMu.Unlock()
  return service[name]
}
```

So far, so good. What's confusing me is this:

The accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095751/understanding-goroutines) suggests that a CPU-bound goroutine will any starve other goroutines that have been multiplexed onto the same OS thread (unless we explicitly yield with `runtime.Gosched()`). Which makes sense.

To me, the `RegisterService()` and `LookupService()` functions above look to be CPU bound, as there's no IO and no yield. Is this correct?

If it is, and if **GOMAXPROCS is set to 1**, then is a mutex in the above example still strictly necessary? Doesn't the fact that the goroutines are CPU-bound at the point where race conditions might occur take care of it?

Even if it does, I presume that in real life using a mutex is here is still a good idea as we may not be able to guarantee what GOMAXPROCS is set to. Are there another reasons?

Comment: The fact that the Go routines are CPU bound does not mean that there is no chance of sheduling happening inbetween. The Mutex is still neccessary.

Comment: Thanks. So a CPU-bound goroutine might starve other goroutines on the same OS thread, or it might not. We can't guarantee it either way. If so, do you know what factors determine whether a goroutines starves others or not?

Comment: A CPU Bound goroutine used to starve others on the same thread but Go 1.2 (almost released) has a pre-emptive scheduler so that is no longer the case.  It was only ever an implementation detail IMHO. (In go 1.2 every function call is an opportunity for pre-emption so if your CPU bound function doesn't call other functions it will starve others on the same thread).

Comment: @AlexEdwards If your code makes any assumptions about the behavior of the scheduler, it exploits undefined behavior. Don't write such a code. Assume the scheduler might switch between Goroutines at every point in your code.

Comment: @NickCraig-Wood you could probably post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As FUZxxl and Nick Craig-Wood noted, current behavior of goroutines is implementation-specific. So, maybe, read or write to map can yield. Considering that [maps are not thread safe](http://golang.org/doc/faq#atomic_maps), mutex or another syncronization is required for correct concurrent access.

As alternative to mutex, you can spawn a goroutine, that performs all operations on your map and talk to it with channels:

```
type writereq struct {
    key string
    value net.Addr
    reply chan struct{}
}

type readreq struct {
    key string
    reply chan net.Addr
}

var service map[string]net.Addr
var reads = make(chan readreq)
var writes = make(chan writereq)

func RegisterService(name string, addr net.Addr) {
    w := writereq{name, addr, make(chan struct{})}
    writes <- w
    return <-w.reply // return after registration confirmation
}

func LookupService(name string) net.Addr {
    r := readreq{name, make(chan net.Addr)}
    reads <- r
    return <-r.reply
}

func serveRegistry() {
    for {
        select {
        case r := <-reads:
            r.reply <- service[r.name]
        case w := <-writes:
            service[w.name] = w.addr
            w.reply <- struct{}
        }
    }
}
```