# Does time.Sleep() yield to other goroutines?

Tags: go, concurrency, scheduling

In Go, does a call to time.Sleep() yield to other goroutines? I have a feeling it does, but in other answers (eg: [Understanding goroutines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095751/understanding-goroutines)) time.Sleep is not explicitly listed as a scheduling point.

Comment: Yes. Though sleep is special in a sense, all function calls are yield points.

Comment: While I know syscalls yield, do you have a reference for "all function calls are yield points"? I haven't been able to find substantiation for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. See [Pre-emption in the scheduler](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.2#preemption).

> In prior releases, a goroutine that was looping forever could starve out other goroutines on the same thread, a serious problem when GOMAXPROCS provided only one user thread. In Go 1.2, this is partially addressed: The scheduler is invoked occasionally upon entry to a function. This means that any loop that includes a (non-inlined) function call can be pre-empted, allowing other goroutines to run on the same thread.

Following design docs are also good reads to learn more about scheduler:

- [Scalable Go Scheduler Design Doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1TTj4T2JO42uD5ID9e89oa0sLKhJYD0Y_kqxDv3I3XMw/edit)
- [Go Preemptive Scheduler Design Doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ETuA2IOmnaQ4j81AtTGT40Y4_Jr6_IDASEKg0t0dBR8/edit)

Comment: "... any loop that includes a (non-inlined) function call can be pre-empted..." Since the Go compiler decides when to do inlining, how will I know whether the function I choose to call as a yield point in my loop will be inlined or not? For example, the `Time.IsZero()` function seems like a prime candidate for inlining, so it seems like the only way to use it reliably as a yield point would be to wrap it in a function that I write and mark with a `//go:noinline` pragma. This seems cumbersome enough that I think I must be misunderstanding something. What am I missing?